# How to interpret conflicting status data between `smartctl` and `mdadm`?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, software-raid, mdadm, smartctl

I have a HDD which is a member of a RAID10 array.
`smartctl` and `mdadm` give me conflicting indications of its status.

`smartctl` claims that the disk is FAILED:

```
$ sudo smartctl -H /dev/sdf
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-5.0.0-2.el7.elrepo.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
Failed Attributes:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   001   001   005    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 2005
```

But `mdadm` claimed that the HDD is fine (active sync):

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0 
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri Jan 31 12:52:57 2020
        Raid Level : raid10
        Array Size : 11720531968 (11177.57 GiB 12001.82 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 2930132992 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
      Raid Devices : 8
     Total Devices : 8
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Jun  4 00:29:34 2020
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 8
   Working Devices : 8
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : near=2
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : 24port:0  (local to host 24port)
              UUID : 3d7b58f8:29553a3d:fbbc536e:8bb95424
            Events : 40771

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sda1
       8      65       16        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdr
       2       8       17        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdb1
       3       8       33        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sdc1
       4       8       49        4      active sync set-A   /dev/sdd1
       5       8       65        5      active sync set-B   /dev/sde1
       6       8       81        6      active sync set-A   /dev/sdf1
       7       8       97        7      active sync set-B   /dev/sdg1
```

Whom should I believe?

Answer (score 2):

These are not conflicting. The *test result* is failed, the drive is not (yet). The drive is currently working, as indicated by the `mdadm` output, however, according to `smartctl`, it is dying and not much of it is left (having used almost all of its spare sectors to relocate data).

I would change that disk, and quickly if that array holds anything critical. Maybe it is a good idea to get some tool from the manufacturer and check the drive with that, in the case `smartctl` is wrong. Usually, it is not though, so your best bet is to change the disk while it works.

Comment: Lacek is totally right.  SMART stats give you a leading indicator of failure.  But md won't actually kick the drive out until it fails a read or a write.  That day is coming soon for this drive.